# Math competition integral problem

Tags: integration, derivatives, contest-math, gaussian-integral

> Suppose $$f(x)=\left(\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt \right)^2 $$ and $$ g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^{2}{(t^{2}+1)}}}{t^{2}+1}dt. 
> $$
>   1) Find $f'(x)+g'(x)$.
>
> 2) Show that $f(x)+g(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I have no idea how to deal with this kind of questions. Any advice is appreciated.

The exam in which this question appeared is already over. I just want to learn how to deal with this type of question.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Sweet problem! I like it!

Comment: A math competition is about "who is best in math," not "who is best in cheating."

Comment: It is already over. I just want to learn how to solve this kind of problems. It is not cheating, it is desire to learn.

Comment: and the appropriate [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-Et3vIbJdE)...

Comment: It is important to show context, for instance which competition, which level and in such cases some link to it and to its dead-line may be fair. But in any case, please show the own efforts to solve the problem. This is the way it works... What is a first attempt to compute $f'$ and/or $g'$?

Comment: Part 2) seems to me to be a very big hint about what the answer to part 1) should be.

Comment: +1. The problem seems nice, and if the exam was already over, the effort is implied.

Comment: See also: [Sum of derivative of integrals: $f(x)=\left(\int\limits_0 ^{x} e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2$ and $g(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42365) There is also a separate question about $g'(x)$: [Derivative of $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{1+t^2} dt $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108021)

Comment: I found those links [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24g(x)%3D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B-x%5E%7B2%7D%7B(t%5E%7B2%7D%2B1)%7D%7D%7D%7Bt%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7Ddt%24&p=1) See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h$ be the function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, 
$$
h(x) = 
\sqrt{f(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}\; dt \ .
$$
Then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f'(x)
&= 2h(x)\; h'(x)=2h(x)\cdot e^{-x^2}\ ,\\
g'(x)
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2(t^{2}+1)}}{t^2+1}\;dt
\\
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\frac{e^{-x^2(t^{2}+1)}}{t^2+1}\;dt
\\
&=
\int_0^1
-2x\;e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}\;dt
=
-2\;e^{-x^2}\;\int_{t\in[0,1]}
e^{-(tx)^2}\;\underbrace{x\; dt}_{d(tx)}
\\
&\qquad\text{ Substitution: }u=tx\ ,\ du=x\; dt\ ,\
u\in[0,x]\ ,
\\
&=-2\; e^{-x^2}\int_{u\in[0,x]}e^{-u^2}\; du=-2e^{-x^2}\; h(x)\ .
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ This implies: }
\\
f'(x)+g'(x) &= 0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the function $f+g$ is a constant function. We only need to compute it in a special point, say in zero. Of course $f(0)=h(0)^2=0^2=0$, and for $g(0)$ we have to compute
$$
g(0)
=\int_0^1
\frac{e^{-0^2(t^{2}+1)}}{t^2+1}\;dt
=\int_0^1
\frac1{t^2+1}\;dt\ .
$$
**Which is the value of the last integral?!**

Comment: You have a slight typo in the first line. It should be $$h(x) = \sqrt{f(x)} = \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes, thanks, this is important!

Comment: Thanks, for your response. Your solution is genuine